# RSA key-pair failing for SSH connection

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-keys, rsa

Password authentication works flawlessly, but I cant get the PubkeyAuthentication to work.

This is what I ran. I added the options to force Pubkey authentication since that is the one that does not connect.

`C:\Users\jerem>ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes admin@192.168.1.32`

`admin@192.168.1.32: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).`

**Setup**

On the local pc I ran `ssh-keygen`. I did not create a passphrase, and left the names default. E.g `id_rsa/id_rsa.pub`.

On the remote PC, I made the following additions to the configuration file:

```
*****config.txt*****      //This is supposed to be a txt file right?

PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication yes
KeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

I also created `authorized_keys` in the same directory (`C:/Users/jerem/.ssh/`). I pasted the local PC's `id_rsa.pub` contents into it verbatim (including the PC name at the end). I will not show this for obvious reasons.

**Verbose:**

```
C:\Users\jerem>ssh -vv -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes admin@192.168.1.32
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.32 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.32 [192.168.1.32] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.32:22 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:4hcl10QXQC9frrHhgVIRi6nl6i9MNcV840nlk92fUsg
debug1: Host '192.168.1.32' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5CRx6/Q5vaGvGn93kkG9FSBrbJnleYGvzqW3XjNbZg0
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5CRx6/Q5vaGvGn93kkG9FSBrbJnleYGvzqW3XjNbZg0
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\jerem/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
admin@192.168.1.32: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Comment: I suspect this may be caused by too lax permissions on `authorized_keys` file or on any of the directories leading to it. I would suggest running server in debugging mode (-d options) to check this out if we talked Linux here but I don't know how to do it on WIndows. And I have no idea how to fix it on Windows if this is the case.

Comment: There is a different error code if authorized_keys is not reachable, so I doubt that is the issue. I'm also unfamiliar with debug mode on  windows... is that even possible to run with OpenSSH?

Comment: On Windows you probably can't run sshd -d "manually", but you *can* still enable debug-level logging through `sshd_config`, using the `LogLevel` option. (And really that would be the recommended way on Linux, too.) Only question is where Windows-OpenSSH puts the log messages... they could be in EventVwr somewhere, but I _think_ I saw them going into files as well.

Comment: @JeremiahDuane I agree to disagree. ssh client WILL loudly complain about permissions on client side - private keys and .ssh directory. However you WILL NOT see anything related to the server side and this is where `authorized_keys` file is located. Regardless that your best shot is to try to enable more verbose logging on the server side so please excercise @user1686 suggestion.